# Changing the font size in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe, pdf-generation

I'd like to change the size of the non-embedded font in a pdf document but am not able to find pdf's font spec on the web. How could it be done?

Note: It doesn't matter if the text overflows the specified paper as a result.

Answer (score 4):

[The PDF Spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)  But that might not be what you were asking for.

Changing the font resource won't change the point size of the font in question (barring some Really Strange alterations).

Font size is set in content streams.  To change a font's size without altering anything else on the page can be Very Hard.  Some things in PDF are positioned absolutely, some relatively... sorta.  Everything is relative but folks regularly save the graphic state, Do Stuff, then restore it back to a blank slate.

Doing this in an existing PDF will involve some serious content stream parsing.  It is non-trivial for someone with a great deal of PDF experience, and... *impractical* for a novice.

What's the purpose of resizing the text?  Perhaps we can come up with something more realistic if we know more about what your goal is.